# Disable non-standard local formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I just spend a day to figure out why a formula was't working as expected. I tried to create a table uting data from an external source.

Collecting data X=period (text), Y=code (num), Z = amount (cur)
The first row =Y, First column = Y, data = Z
The data is collected by period and code. If a code is not found in the range, the code will be added in the next available cell in the first row.

I want to show the code as a 3 digit format, thus I formatted the range having the codes (VBA) .Numformat="000"
I want to display the codes as a fixed code of 3 digits, so I applied a VBA instruction to format the range to `.NumberFormat = "000"`.
When importing a new line of data, it is checked if the code already exists in the table. If not, the code is added to the next available blank cell on the first row. The following function is used for this purpose:

```
Public Function SearchValCol(lngSearch) As Long

    'Search a a specific value in a column and return the column number if found.

    Dim Rng As Range
    With ws_per_tot.Range("1:1")
        Set Rng = .Find( _
            What:=lngSearch, _
            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, _
            searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        SearchValCol = Rng.Column
    End If

End Function
```

Now, something odd is happening when formatting the cells as "000". When the cell is formatted as "standard", the code is found, when formatted as "000" it is not. Furthermore, if the format "000" is applied, Excel shows that "special formatting" is used

[image: Chinese(Taiwan) format]

I read that there is a problem with finding values in formatted cells and assume this cauced my annoyance today as well. I strongly prefer to disable special locational formatting. Chances that I shall use these is 0.0001%. Anyone have an idea?

Art.

Comment: use `Lookin:=xlFormulas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not well documented, but it has been my observation that, with regard to the `LookIn` parameter, `xlValues` examines what is displayed, whereas `xlFormulas` examines the contents of the formula bar.

Hence, if you change to `LookIn:=xlFormulas`, you should be able to execute your `.Find` no matter the format of the cell.

I don't know why entering a format of `000` causes the Format Cell dialog box to select a Taiwanese special format. I assume that is a special format in Taiwan.  It seems that something has changed in Excel, perhaps a bug, where if you enter a number of digits that corresponds to a special format in some other locale, the Format Cell dialog switches to that.

I would hope they will get it fixed.  Until then, if it is an issue, you can use a region specific format.  For example, in the US, you could use `[$-en-US]000` instead of the plain `000`.

Comment: Thank you! This exactly did the trick. Don't know either why this happens. 000 is a defined locate in Taiwan apparently. If you format for example 0000, Excel assumes a postal code in Portugal and 00000 a postal code in Basque. Its quite annoying and I believe this is something that a user wants definitely control of.